# How to show WebView2 content without flicker?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

In my UWP project, a page contains several subpages. One subpage has a WebView2(from Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls). And I need to use it to open some link, e.g. [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com), only once. When navigate to the web page done, I need to switch to other subpage and back then.

I find that the WebView2's content will flicker: from black to the web content. The flicker issue is caused by WebView2's visibility change.

Below is my code, any advise?

UI:

```
<Page
    x:Class="WebView2FlickerDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WebView2FlickerDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="200" Height="100"></Button>

        <controls:WebView2 x:Name="WebView2" Height="567.55" Width="792" Margin="200 150 0 0" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="Blue" Height="567.55" Width="792" Margin="200 150 0 0" Visibility="Collapsed"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    StartWebView2();
}

private async void StartWebView2()
{
    try
    {
        await WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        WebView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https:///www.bing.com");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (WebView2.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        WebView2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (WebView2.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        WebView2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same behavior. Since I don't know your specific scenario, based on the code provided so far, if you don't want the current flickering behavior, it is recommended to delete the `WebView2.Visibility` part and use `myGrid` to cover the webview2.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myGrid.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            // WebView2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            //WebView2.Opacity = 1;
            myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (myGrid.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            //WebView2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            //WebView2.Opacity = 0;
            myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```